# Should I use aspnetdb for other stuff than users, roles and such?

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm pretty new into asp.net, and currently I have the need for storing various information in a database. Since I have used the standard Login control in asp.net, I already have the ASPNETDB database in my application.

My question is: Is it good practice to use this database for other things than user and role information?

Regards, Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to store the user/profile information in your normal SQL Database, therefore not using the ASPNETDB, but migrating all the tables and data to your application DB.

Comment: So you mean: Move everything from ASPNETDB to a normal SQL database, and then use the normal SQL database to store all information I need to store?

Comment: This is correct, you can use any database as your profile/user store.